# How to correctly write down a summation used in a simulation

Tags: summation

I am unclear on how to mathematically write a summation that is used in my simulation. I am trying to calculate the fluorescence for a slab with ends of -L and +L.  There are currently 200 slices within the slab each of constant thickness, $\Delta x$. The fluorescence for each slice, $\Delta x$, varies and to get the fluorescence for the entire slab, I would just add all of the fluorescences for the individual slices together.

The fluorescence in a slice is given by:

\begin{equation}FL_{\Delta x,r}=\frac{FL_{OH,r}\Delta x}{s_{m,r}}\end{equation}

where $FL_{\Delta x,r}$ is the fluorescence in the slice and $FL_{OH,r}$ is the fluorescence for a constant hydroxide ion concentration in a thickness of $s_{m,r}$ (which comes from experimental data). It is assumed that a particular slice has this constant hydroxide ion concentration (the hydroxide ion concentration and therefore the fluorescence is different in each slice).  To convert from the fluorescence in the thickness  $s_{m,r}$ to the slice thickness, ${\Delta x}$, the RHS is multiplied by $\frac{\Delta x}{s_{m,r}}$.

Now in order to get the fluorescence for the slab that extends from -L to +L and has 200 slices in it, I need to sum all of the slice fluorescences. This is where I start to have problems with notation.  Here is what I have so far,

\begin{equation}FL_{slab,r}=\sum_{n=-L}^{+L}FL_{\Delta x,r}=\sum_{n=-L}^{+L}\frac{FL_{OH,r}\Delta x}{s_{m,r}}\end{equation}

I don't know how to substitute in for n. I don't even know if n should be used.  $\Delta x$ is not an integer and I need to make it clear, I think, that the summation steps forward by values of $\Delta x$.

Also,  $\Delta x$ is constant thickness for each slice.  I'm not sure how I could pull it out of the summation, because it is the variable by which the summation steps forward.  Perhaps I can't pull it out; I don't know.

How do I write this summation correctly, say for a journal article.

Comment: What is $r$?  The slice number? A value in $[-L, L]$?

Comment: Isn't $\sum\limits_{n=-L}^L c$ just $(2L+1)\, c$?

Comment: r is a distance from a reference point.  The hydroxide ion concentrations vary with both $\Delta x$ and r.  The experimental thickness, $s_m$, also varies with r.  r is not a slice number. If a slice number is needed, let's use j.  Also $\Delta x$ never varies in magnitude regardless of the distance from the reference point, r.

Comment: I should have said that the hydroxide ion concentration varies with both the slice number and r.

Comment: As a result of your questions, I'm thinking that a large part of the problem is that I didn't include a slice number.  So instead of $\Delta x$, I should have used $\Delta x_j$

Comment: I think I understand now. The slices aren't stacked between each other and the reference point, they're side-by-side, correct?  One more thing- if $r$ is the distance to the reference point, shouldn't each slice have a different $r$ value (unless they curve around the reference point, or the difference is negligible)? Which one does $FL_{slab,r}$ use then (the center?)

Comment: Yes, the slices are side by side.  The slab which contains the slices is moving away from the reference point.  Should each slice have a different r value?  I don't know.  The slab moves away from r, but the slices within the slab aren't affected.  There is always the same number of slices and the width of the slice never changes anywhere. Its the fluorescence emitted by the hydroxide ion concentration and the thickness, $s_m$ that vary with r.  For example, the fluorescence at a pH of 10 might be 140 at $r_1$ but 138 at $r_2$, which might only be 100 microns further downstream.

Comment: I guess the question to ask then is:  is there anything that distinguishes one slice from another in your formula? If the slice width is constant, and if all slices are the same distance $r$ away, then they should be equal in terms of florescence. In that case, just multiply by the count- 200

Comment: Maybe a sketch might clarify things. Can you edit your question to add one?

Comment: @user619894   In my comment below, I think I clarified it without a sketch.  The simulation is a double loop.  The outer loop is with time i (or alternatively distance, r) and the innerloop calculates the fluorescence for the slab slices based on the loop parameter j.  So this is a typical unsteady state problem.  The slab moves away from the reference point with time (i) and at any time, i, I want to calculate the fluorescence within the slab, which is done using the space parameter, j.

Answer (score 0):

You may want something like the following, which sums each of the 200 slices, where the distance of a slice from the reference point $r$ is parameterized in terms of the slice index $j$.

\begin{align}
FL_{slab,r} = \Delta x\sum_{j=1}^{200}\frac{FL_{OH,r_{j}}}{s_{m,r_{j}}}
\end{align}

If it turns out that a slice's distance from the reference point is constant with respect to $j$, then we will be able to remove the subscript and pull that factor out of the summation.

Comment: No, I don't think this is right.  The whole slab, which contains the 200 slices, is a distance r from the reference point.  j would need to refer to $\Delta x$ and not r.  If a subscript is to be used for r, it would be "i".  The distance r is directly related to time.  The simulation steps forward in time, but at any time, the fluorescence withing the slab needs to be calculated.  The slices fluorescences vary with space, j, at any time i.  So a double loop, with i as the outer loop parameter and j as the inner loop parameter.  Maybe I can work up a drawing if this is still not understandable

Comment: The fluorescence of the whole slab will change as the slab moves away from the reference point.  I have chosen r where r is a variable distance, but i could be used as well to denote the time elapsed in moving away from the reference point.

Comment: Replacing r with i, maybe;\begin{align}
FL_{slab,i} = \sum_{j=1}^{200}\frac{FL_{OH,i,j}\Delta x_j}{s_{m,i}}
\end{align}

Comment: Also, how does -L and +L impact the summation equation.  The exact middle of the slab is at `zero.  The summation needs to start with the first slice that starts at -L and ending with the last slice that starts at +L.

Comment: Correction:  The summation needs to start with the first slice that starts at -L and ending with the last slice that ENDS at +L.

Comment: @rdemyan you said that the slice width $\delta x$ never changes though, so we don't need to parameterize it in terms of the slice.

Comment: "Also, how does -L and +L impact the summation equation" this is pretty much the question I was asking you in the comments when I asked "is there anything that distinguishes one slice from another in your formula?" If there isn't, then $L$ and $-L$ don't matter, and we just multiply by 200.

Comment: I think a drawing would help a lot.  I also didn't realize that there was another summation- over time.  Do you have fixed increments ($+2 ns$ from $[0, 10000]$), or is it supposed to be continuous? In the case of the latter, you'd want an integral

Comment: Yes, the time increment, i, is fixed, but I'm looking for the equation at a specific value of i and am only interested in the j summation.  Here's what I think the final equation is:                                                  
\begin{align} FL_{slab,i} = \frac{\Delta x}{s_{m,i}}\sum_{j=1}^{j_{max}}{FL_{OH,i,j}} \end{align}

where $j_{max}$ replaces 200.  $s_{m,i}$ is constant at a specific value of i and $\Delta x$ never varies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137063/discussion-between-dillon-davis-and-rdemyan).